# WARNING: unknown mimetype for PDF filetype on Sphynx | Read The Docs

Tags: python-3.x, read-the-docs

```
Python 3.10
Sphynx 7.1.2
Pydata Sphynx Theme 0.15.2
Read The Docs
```

I have some PDF files in _static and they have for some reason started causing warnings. They have been there through some previous builds and did not cause a problem. The only thing I have done since then is add some folders and .rst files to the docs. But I have not linked to those PDF from anywhere.

Warnings

```
writing mimetype file...
writing META-INF/container.xml file...
writing content.opf file...
WARNING: unknown mimetype for _static/papers/A-New-Smart-Contract-Solution-V1.1.pdf, ignoring
WARNING: unknown mimetype for _static/papers/M_Assets_Whitepaper.pdf, ignoring
WARNING: unknown mimetype for _static/papers/name_ride_WhitepaperV1.1-2.pdf, ignoring
WARNING: unknown mimetype for _static/papers/name_Litepaper.pdf, ignoring
WARNING: unknown mimetype for _static/papers/name_Structure_WhitepaperV1.3.pdf, ignoring
writing nav.xhtml file...
writing toc.ncx file...
writing name.epub file...
Updating searchtools for Read the Docs search... build finished with problems, 5 warnings.
```

Kinda stumped!

Tried a few different ways to import mimetypes but no love, such as.

```
import mimetypes
mimetypes.add_type('application/pdf', '.pdf')
```

```
from sphinx.util import mimetypes
mimetypes.add_type('application/pdf', '.pdf')
```

Comment: Try adding `suppress_warnings = ['epub.unknown_project_files']` to your `conf.py`. Source: https://github.com/IQSS/dataverse/pull/3542/files